# How can one distribute Haskell programs to non-technical end users?

Tags: haskell

I am just starting to learn Haskell so please forgive me if this question has an obvious answer. I'm interested in writing programs to distribute to end users who might know how to use their Terminal application but not necessarily how to program or install Haskell and Haskell libraries on their system.

How would one go about packaging up a Haskell program (e.g. a command line tool or a more complex application) and distributing it to this sort of userbase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ghc -o hello hello.hs
```

compiles the .hs as a frozen binary, so for windows the user would just double click the hello.exe, and for linux it's ./hello .

Comment: And of course with `--make` when you have more than one file.

Comment: Does that compile in all of the program's Haskell library dependencies into the same executable?

Comment: Also, does the compiled version target a particular architecture, or can it usually run on both OS X and Linux?

Comment: @dan: Native executables *can't* run on different platforms (at least not without extra emulation effort on all but one platforms).

Comment: I think shared/dynamic linked libraries will need to be installed independently on the target machine, if you make use of them that is. For Windows this is probably as easy as dropping the required DLL's in the directory of your newly created exe. For Linux one would want to use their package repository like apt or yum. For OS X, no clue.

Comment: @Htbaa: IMHO usually, haskell links everything statically. For dynamic linking, use `--dynamic`, but it won't work as most libs aren't available dynamically.

Comment: I have no experience with that, but depending on the software license statically linking all dependent libraries could violate the software license (LGPL licensed libraries for example).

Comment: Could you precompile a Haskell app for OS X and various Linux architectures into executables for download, or is the apt-get/yum strategy safer?

Comment: @Htbaa: As all libs have a BSD license, there's no problem for licensing. Just include a line "runtime environment (c)..." into your code, but IANAL

Comment: @FUZxxl - all GHC libs, and many Hackage libs, have a BSD license, but by no means all of them.  If you're distributing binaries, you need to comply with the licenses of all linked libraries.

Comment: GHC doesn't link absolutely everything statically - you may see binaries breaking on some platforms due to mismatched [libc](http://code.google.com/p/hledger/issues/detail?id=36), [libiconv](http://code.google.com/p/hledger/issues/detail?id=40), or such things.

Answer (score 5):

If they are windows users then use the [bamse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bamse) package to build an installer for your application.  If not then look for distro-specific packaging suggestions.  Perhaps someone else can explain OS X packaging.